# How to Show Push Notifications on another ViewController. I am receiveing it on Appdelegate page on all the three cases

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

Please tell me how to send the appdelegate to another viewcontroller using NSdoctionary and receive it on the new view controller and show it.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification: (NSDictionary*)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"Push received: %@", userInfo);
}
```

Comment: You need to check for your view controller from self.navigationController.viewControllers and send your controller to the respective one

Answer (score 4):

There are few ways/ But I prefer using https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html

**Somrewere in constants**

```
NSString *const NOTIFICATION_ID = @"com.yourapp.notificationID";
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSNotificationCenter * notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notificationCenter addObserver:self
                               selector:@selector(notificationRecieved:)
                                   name:NOTIFICATION_ID
                                 object:nil];
}

- (void)notificationRecieved:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Push received: %@", notification.userInfo);
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NOTIFICATION_ID object:nil];
}
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification: (NSDictionary*)userInfo 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_ID object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

Comment: NSString *const NOTIFICATION_ID = @"com.yourapp.notificationID"; Where i need to put that code

Comment: In fact, you can just replace NOTIFICATION_ID with @"com.yourapp.notificationID".

Answer (score 0):

Use Notifications. The app delegate will post the notification with the notification dictionary, the view controller will be listening for it.

Comment: This is basic iOS programming - there are numerous examples here or you can google NSNotificationCenter. If you do not understand how notifications function you won't be able to address any problems. Note that the push notification may not be on the main thread.